# Parsing website with BeautifulSoup and Requests returns None

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Im a beginner in programming all together and work on a project of mine. For that I'm trying to parse data from a website to make a tool that uses the data. I found that BeatifulSoup and Requests are common tools to do it, but unfortunately i can not seem to make it work. It always returns the value None or an error where it says:

"TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable"

Did i do anything wrong? Is it maybe not possible to parse some websites data and I'm being restricted the access or something?

If there are other ways to access the data im happy to hear as well.

Here is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

pickrates = {}      # dict to store winrate of champions for each position
source = requests.get("http://u.gg/lol/champions/aatrox/build?role=top").text

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, "lxml")
value = soup.find("div", class_="content-section champion-ranking-stats")
print(value.prettify())
```

Comment: In which line you got that error ? please provide full error message

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Mike\Python_Projects\BlindPickGG\riot_api_test.py", line 9, in <module>
    print(value.prettify())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'prettify'
[Finished in 0.567s]

Comment: Is the `selenium` solution below worked? @MikeWerner

Answer (score 0):

Remember when you request a webpage with *requests* module, you will only get the html of that page. I mean this module is not capable of rendering JavaScript.

Try this code:

```
import requests

source = requests.get("http://u.gg/lol/champions/aatrox/build?role=top").text
print(source)
```

Then search for the class names you provided by hand(ctrl + f), there is no such elements at all. It means those are generated by other requests like ajax. They are somehow created **after** the initial html page is loaded. So before Beautiful soup comes to the party, you can't get them even in `.text` attribute of the response object.

One way of doing it is to [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) or any other libraries which handles the JS.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this question ([can't find html tag when I scrape web using beautifulsoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70235911/cant-find-html-tag-when-i-scrape-web-using-beautifulsoup)), the problem would be caused by the **JavaScript event listener**. I would suggest you to use `selenium` to handle this issue. So, let apply `selenium` at sending request and getting back page source and then use `BeautifulSoup` to parse it.

Don't forget to download a browser driver from https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/getting_started/installing_browser_drivers/ and place it in the same directory with your code.

The example of code below is using `selenium` with Firefox:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'http://u.gg/lol/champions/aatrox/build?role=top'
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'html.parser')
time.sleep(1)
browser.close()
value = soup.find("div", class_="content-section champion-ranking-stats")
print(value.prettify())
```

Your expected output would be like:

> ```
> >>> print(value.prettify())
> <div class="content-section champion-ranking-stats">
>  <div class="win-rate meh-tier">
>   <div class="value">
>    48.4%
>   </div>
>   <div class="label">
>    Win Rate
>   </div>
>  </div>
>  <div class="overall-rank">
>   <div class="value">
>    49 / 58
>   </div>
>   <div class="label">
>    Rank
>   </div>
>  </div>
>  <div class="pick-rate">
>   <div class="value">
>    3.6%
>   </div>
>   <div class="label">
>    Pick Rate
>   </div>
>  </div>
>  <div class="ban-rate">
>   <div class="value">
>    2.3%
>   </div>
>   <div class="label">
>    Ban Rate
>   </div>
>  </div>
>  <div class="matches">
>   <div class="value">
>    55,432
>   </div>
>   <div class="label">
>    Matches
>   </div>
>  </div>
> </div>
> ```